# PyTorch Softmax Dimensions error

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm attempting to write a simple NN module, with 2 layers, first layer ReLU activation, output softmax with 3 classes (one-hot encoded). It seems theres something wrong with the way I'm using the softmax function, but I'm not sure what's going on.

X is 178x13
Y is 178x3

Dataset I'm using is fairly simple, and can be found [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine).

I keep getting the error:

```
RuntimeError: dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-2, 1], but got 3) .
```

.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

# Read in dataset, specifying that this set didn't come with column headers
x = pd.read_csv('Datasets/wine.data', header=None)

# Rename columns
x.columns = ['Class', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12', 'A13']

y = x[['Class']].values

#turn class labels into one-hot encoding
one_hot = LabelBinarizer()
y = Variable(torch.from_numpy(one_hot.fit_transform(y)), )

x = Variable(torch.from_numpy(x.iloc[:, 1:14].values).float())


N, D_in, H, D_out = y.shape[0], x.shape[1], 20, 3

# Implement neural net with nn module

model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(D_in, H),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(H, D_out),
    torch.nn.LogSoftmax(dim=3)
)

loss_fn = torch.nn.NLLLoss

learning_rate = 1e-4
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

for t in range(500):
    y_pred = model(x)

    loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
    print("Iteration: %d | Loss: %.3f" % (t, loss))

    optimizer.zero_grad()

    loss.backward()

    optimizer.step()
```

Comment: What is the size of x and y? why not just use random x, y to demonstrate your ideas? In its current form, your code can not be debugged and run, which makes it less likely to be answered. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create minimal, complete and verifiable examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem because for NLLLoss:

```
The target that this loss expects is a class index (0 to N-1, where N = number of classes)
```

And I had been trying to give it the one-hot encoded vector. I solved my issue by doing:

```
loss = loss_fn(y_pred, torch.max(y, 1)[1])
```

Where torch.max found the maximum values and their respective index.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you have misunderstood the argument `dim` of `LogSoftmax`. From the documentation,

> dim (int) – A dimension along which Softmax will be computed (so every
>   slice along dim will sum to 1).

Now, after you pass your input through your two linear layers, the tensor you get and to which you apply `LogSoftmax` has dimensions `178 x 3`. Clearly, `dim = 3` is not available as your tensor only has two dimensions. Instead, try `dim=1`for summing across columns.

Comment: Ah ok; I had suspected maybe that was it, but when I try, it just throws me a different error that I also cannot interpret: RuntimeError: multi-target not supported at /Users/soumith/code/builder/wheel/pytorch-src/torch/lib/THNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c:22

Comment: alright. let me try it myself. I'll get back to you.

Comment: what PyTorch version are you using btw?